# SQL query for total number of continuous item check

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

SQLITE/SQL Query for  total counts of continuous records, PFA image.
Here I have 1 and 0 in table.
Suppose I want to check the total number of 1 which are exactly in multiple of 3 or you can say countinuous. If zero apperas than it will not considerd.

Example A:- (Column values displayed horizontally)

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

[image]

So the total count of occurance is 8 any sequency divide by 3.

[image]

[EDIT 2]
Consider first column as milliseonds and its in assending order
[image]

Comment: Your question, as it stands now, cannot be answered, because you have not provided a column which provides the _ordering_ to be used when finding islands of `1 1 1`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Tim
I didn't get you, can you please explain more.

Comment: You need to add a _third_ column which provides the ordering you see.  SQL tables have **NO** internal order.

Comment: Currently I achieved it with the loop from the cursor I get, if it continue or divided by 3 than I add in the main variable, rest I ignore, so I get the total count. It can't be reordered as occurance of zero will void the case or multiple of 3.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example of ordering and how it will work here?

Comment: Sophia, I think you miss the point. Imagine that a plain SELECT of your table would produce rows in an undetermined order, even different each time you execute it, then obviously the result would also be different. So you need to somehow determine in what the order these records need to be traversed. You cannot leave it up to "luck".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt to answer your question, considering that we can use the `deviceid` to order the rows and count the sequences

note that in order to work, you should have sqlite version 3.25 at least, because this requires window functions

Creating a test table with an auto-increment `deviceid` column, that will simulate your own data

```
CREATE TABLE "test" (
    "deviceid"  INTEGER,
    "password"  INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("deviceid" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

inserting rows following your own sequence `1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1`

```
DELETE FROM test;
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (1);
```

Solution :

```
select password, sum(div_floor) AS Number_of_3_occurences
FROM (
    select password, count(*) as cnt_sequence, cast(round(count(*) / 3 ) as int) as div_floor
    from (select test.*,
                 (row_number() over (order by deviceid) -
                  row_number() over (partition by password order by deviceid)
                 ) as grp
          from test
         ) t
    group by grp, password
) ttt
where  cnt_sequence>=3
group by password
```

Result

```
password  Number_of_3_occurences
0         2
1         8
```

Comment: Perfect that's what I want,

Comment: Thomas suppose if I have one more column for date time stamp and want to consider the  event occurance between particular time range than how can I modify the query? (Eg occurance between 9:00 AM to 10:30 PM - time must the milliseconds)